# find max, min from a .txt-file which has multiple columns

Tags: numpy, max, minimum

I have a lot of data in a `.txt` file. 
It looks something like this:

```
#   T1  T2  T3  T4  T5  T6  T7  T8
1   20.67   20.70   20.73   20.76   20.69   20.73   20.66   20.72

2   20.68   20.70   20.74   20.75   20.69   20.73   20.66   20.72
```

I want to find the max/min. values using a Python script.

First I tried to find what the maximum of the `T1` column is.
This is my (very, very simple) code:

```
import numpy as np

T1 = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)

T1_max=np.maximum(T1)

print("T1_max")
```

When I try to run it I receive error messages like these:

```
Line #7816 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
Line #7817 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
Line #7818 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
Line #7819 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
Line #7820 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
Line #7821 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
```

(it starts with Line #2 (got 10..).
It has to be the 'np.genfromtxt' function. What argument do I have to add to make it work? Or do you have any idea how to start an alternative script which puts out the max./min. values?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you want debugging help, you should explain clearly  what the specific problem or error is. Right now you haven't stated this in your question, although I can guess that `np.genfromtxt` is not returning what you think it should (hint: [read the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html), specifically the part about the `unpack` argument).

Comment: These are the errors I receive:    Line #7816 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
    >Line #7817 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
    >Line #7818 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
    >Line #7819 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
    >Line #7820 (got 10 columns instead of 1)
    >Line #7821 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
(I just copied the last lines, but it begings with Line #2 (got 10 columns...)

Comment: What do lines 7815 through 7820 look like?  Post them in your question.  Probably the format of your text file is not consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem here was not setting 8 variables. One variable for each of the columns. Also the 'max'-function from python will do the job:

```
T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T8 = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)

T1max = max(T1)
print(T1max)
```